# Loading Models & Library takes too long

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have been building a large social app on Codeigniter.
There is a function which loads 4 Models & 1 Library (5 resources) and then performs some PHP logic & DB insertions/selection etc. These 5 resources are specific to this function and not required frequently hence cant Autoload it.

```
function abc(){

  log_message('error' , 'block 1'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

  $this->load->model('model1');
  $this->load->model('model2');
  $this->load->model('model3');
  $this->load->model('model4');
  $this->load->library('lib1');

  log_message('error' , 'block 2'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
  // Some DB queries performed here

  if(){
     // Some PHP code
  }else{
    // Some PHP code
  }

 // Some DB queries performed here

 log_message('error' , 'block 3'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

By using Codeigniter’s Profiling Class i found that the entire function took around 8 seconds to execute whereas the DB queries in it only amounted for 1 second.
The after logging time at many points in my code, i found that out of 8 seconds, around 6.5 seconds were taken for just loading those libraries & models whereas the processing of code took just more than 1 second.

By doing Profiling of my function and logging time stamp at specific intervals i found that my total function abc takes 8seconds to execute. But the time differece between block 1 & block 2 is 7 seconds whereas the time difference between block 2 and block 3 is just 1 second. So atleast i know that its the loading reasources that takes lot of time nd i dont know why :(

8 second for function execution is just unacceptable and i am unable to figure put the solution. Please help…

The site is hosted on DigitalOcean cloud with 512 MB RAM and only 2 users testing it. Do I need to increase RAM to achieve this. How can I speed this loading time…

Comment: Refactoring? Benchmark test? You might want to add some code if you're looking for help.

Comment: If you can, get a cachegrind profiling output file with [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and feed it to wincachegrind or kcachegrind to get a more granular look at where time goes. This could be an io problem too.

Comment: @complex857 Is there any tutorial or link which shows how to do it ?

Comment: @nick-fury i am already using profiling. Sure i will show my code layout

Comment: @Jigar, You can try [this](http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/) one, basically all you need to do is install the xdebug php extension and fiddle with the ini settings.

Comment: fine..will do it.. Hope it will help me :) thanx @complex857

Answer (score 0):

hard to say "how can you speed up loading time" whithout checking at your lib andm odels code, anyway you should be able to test your app benchmark just putting:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(true);
```

inside a view or a model or a controller.

try that

Comment: It doesnt matter what the code is in my library cause uptil now i have only loaded them but not used/called them. Loading of those files takes too long as i mentioned. Not the execution

Comment: @Jigar so it's your server, or you have thousands and thousands of lines of code inside, reading = parsing anyway